# DNS Different IP for Different Port

Tags: dns, ip

Is it possible to assign a different IP for a different port?

Such as:

http://example.com:80 -> 123.456.789.012

http://example.com:90 -> 987.654.321.098

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DNS SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) to associate a hostname (and thereby an address) *and* a port number to a service name, but virtually no web browsers or other HTTP clients query SRV records.

So, in practice, no.

Even with SRV records, you cannot solve the problem in your question as stated. SRV records won't help you resolve `http://example.com:80/` and `http://example.com:90/` to different addresses, because specifying the port number manually overrides the SRV record and queries for address (A and AAAA) records directly. What SRV records would do (if browsers bothered to query them!) is help you resolve `http://a.example.com/` and `http://b.example.com/` to different addresses (or the same address) and different ports.

Comment: Lol, I am actually hosting a server with another IP, and on wikipedia its says that the client that connects to the server can use SRV records to do this.